# Using depth first search algorithm to solve a maze by finding the shortest path

Tags: python, depth-first-search, shortest-path

I'm trying to demonstrate maze solving with DFS using pygame where a list of line coordinates draws a maze. The rect_pos variable represents the start of the maze and the destination variable represents the goal. I managed to have the algorithm generate a list of all possible locations in the maze, however, I can't figure out how to generate a list of coordinates that shows the shortest path.

Here is the code:

```
MAZE = [
    ((100,100), (300,100)), ((100,100), (100,600)), 
    ((100,600), (600,600)), ((100,200), (300,200)), 
    ((300,200), (300,300)), ((300,300), (500,300)), 
    ((400,100), (400,200)), ((400,200), (500,200)), 
    ((100,400), (200,400)), ((200,400), (200,300)), 
    ((300,500), (300,400)), ((300,400), (400,400)), 
    ((200,500), (500,500)), ((500,500), (500,400)),
    ((400,500), (400,600)), ((400,100), (600,100)),
    ((600,100), (600,600))
    ]

visited = [] # all locations visited
routes = ['U','D','L','R'] # up down left right
rect_pos = (350, 550) # start position


destination = (350,50) # end goal

def dfs(MAZE, rect_pos, destination):

    visited.append(rect_pos)

    if visited[-1] != destination:
        
        for route in routes:
            intersection = False # check if a potential move can happen

            if route == 'U':
                for next in MAZE:
                    x_coord = next[0]
                    y_coord = next[1]
                    robot_next_pos = (rect_pos[0], rect_pos[1] - 50)
                    if robot_next_pos[0] > x_coord[0] and robot_next_pos[0] < y_coord[0] and robot_next_pos[1] == x_coord[1] and robot_next_pos[1] == y_coord[1]:
                        intersection = True

                if intersection == False:    
                    new_rect_pos = (rect_pos[0], rect_pos[1] - 100)
                    if new_rect_pos not in visited:
                        dfs(MAZE, new_rect_pos, destination)

            elif route == 'D':
                for next in MAZE:
                    x_coord = next[0]
                    y_coord = next[1]
                    robot_next_pos = (rect_pos[0], rect_pos[1] + 50)
                    if robot_next_pos[0] > x_coord[0] and robot_next_pos[0] < y_coord[0] and robot_next_pos[1] == x_coord[1] and robot_next_pos[1] == y_coord[1]:
                        intersection = True
                    
                if intersection == False:
                    new_rect_pos = (rect_pos[0], rect_pos[1] + 100)
                    if new_rect_pos not in visited:
                        dfs(MAZE, new_rect_pos, destination)

            elif route == 'L':
                for next in MAZE:
                    x_coord = next[0]
                    y_coord = next[1]
                    robot_next_pos = (rect_pos[0] - 50, rect_pos[1])
                    if robot_next_pos[1] > x_coord[1] and robot_next_pos[1] < y_coord[1] and robot_next_pos[0] == x_coord[0] and robot_next_pos[0] == y_coord[0]:
                        intersection = True
                    
                if intersection == False:
                    new_rect_pos = (rect_pos[0] - 100, rect_pos[1])
                    if new_rect_pos not in visited:
                        dfs(MAZE, new_rect_pos, destination)
            
            elif route == 'R':
                for next in MAZE:
                    x_coord = next[0]
                    y_coord = next[1]
                    robot_next_pos = (rect_pos[0] + 50, rect_pos[1])
                    if robot_next_pos[1] > x_coord[1] and robot_next_pos[1] < y_coord[1] and robot_next_pos[0] == x_coord[0] and robot_next_pos[0] == y_coord[0]:
                        intersection = True
                    
                if intersection == False:
                    new_rect_pos = (rect_pos[0] + 100, rect_pos[1])
                    if new_rect_pos not in visited:
                        dfs(MAZE, new_rect_pos, destination)
                

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dfs(MAZE, rect_pos, destination)
    print('visited: ', visited) # all locations generated
```